# Retrieve name of latest txt file in Command Prompt

Tags: windows, cmd, filenames

I am trying to retrieve the name of the newest .txt file in a directory, on Windows 6.1 , C:\Users\KMST

I have tried the following but it does not seem to work.

```
for /f "delims=" %%x in ('C:\Users\KMST\*.txt /od /b *.*') do @echo %%x
```

But the error I got is, %%x was unexpected at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From command line the syntax for `for` command does not need to escape the percent sign used in the replaceable parameter, so

```
for /f "delims=" %x in ('dir /a-d /b /o-d C:\Users\KMST\*.txt') do @echo %x
```

but this will list all the files in descending date order.

To only get the newest file from command line you can try with

```
dir /a-d /o-d /b "C:\Users\KMST\*.txt" | cmd /v /c"set /p.=&&echo(^!.^!"
```

Comment: Can I ask about files residing in other drives, eg E:\